# After git pull using GitKraken, my local unstaged file disappeared

Tags: git, macos, github, gitkraken

I modified a file locally but I didn't stage or commit it. After I did a git pull, that file got replaced by a version created by my teammate. How can I recovery the version that I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have modified it with an IDE with local history (like [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history), [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/local-history), [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-88.htm), ...) you might still find it there.

[XCode has a local history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682752/6309) too. Or you would need to rely on [TimeMachine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250).

Comment: Thanks. Normally when you do a pull unstaged file will automatically become staged and won't get lost. The reason my file got "replaced" is because of the text editor I used. I used Atom and when I opened the code it alerted me that previous states  existed and asked me whether to discard changes and open in new window. I didn't understand what it means so I clicked discard. That caused me to lose my work instead of the version control software.

Comment: @yughred OK. Did you find back your file though?

Comment: Ended up redoing the work and deleting the terrible text editor, lol.